# Knockout Tree drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, tree, knockout.js

I have a tree whose nodes needs to dragged and dropped on to a div. I have used knockout to create the tree. The tree is a lazy loaded and working fine.

The tree has a feature where user can drag and drop nodes onto a panel beside.

I am able to achieve single drag and drop but not able to do multiple drag and drop. Here is the fiddle that I have created for single drag and drop http://jsfiddle.net/anirbankundu/TKVdJ/6

I am not able to do multiple drag and drop on to the panel beside
Basically user can check the nodes they want to drop on the panel. Then at one go the nodes should be dropped on the desired panel.

Can somebody let me know how to achieve this ?

Thanks